# Implement RDF in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdf

I'm looking for a way to simulate (implement) RDF in SQL, I'm not going to convert RDF to SQL or stuff like that, I want to apply RDF concept in SQL Server to benefit it's advantages, again I'm not supposed to use SPARQL

As you probably know, RDF is a triple involving **Subject - Predicate - Object**, I was wondering if I could make a table in SQL server like following figure:

```
ID  | Subject | Predicate | Object
----------------------------------
    |         |           |
```

Or maybe two tables with a foreign key:

```
ID | Subject
------------
   |

ID  | Subject_ID  |Predicate | Object
---------------------------------------
    |             |          |
```

I supposed it's something others have already done. I searched a lot but I found nothing that is really useful. I appreciate it if you suggest a way or offer a link to a ready to use tool.

Comment: Let's disregard for the moment that IMO this is not a good idea (this approach is more likely to give the worst of both worlds than any sort of advantage). Apart from that, it's not really clear what your question actually is. Yes, you could make an SQL table like you show in the first figure. You could also create the two tables with a foreign key (though I'd probably extend it to have also predicate and object reference via a foreign key). Are you asking which approach to pick? How would we know? We have no idea what you're trying to achieve here, what your use case is.

Comment: What are you asking for? How you can model RDF in a relational database? Doesn't it depend on how complex you want to have the SQL queries then?

Comment: Honestly, it looks like you're figuring it out. If there isn't a publicly available tool, you can be the one to make it! StackOverflow can help if you get stuck. Also, my opinion, but you might be headed for pain if you're trying to avoid using SqlServer how it was meant to be used.

Answer (score -1):

In the Relational Model each table represents one or more Predicates about a particular kind of subject.

So one or more tables per Subject, with each Predicate modeled as a Column, and the corresponding Object stored in the Predicate's Column

```
Subject_ID  |Predicate1 | Predicate2
---------------------------------------
124         | True      |  'Chicken'
```

If a Predicate has multiple Objects, then you would use a related table.